# Can I make and host bitcoin wallet in my own website to get rid of using 3rd party wallets

Tags: bitcoind

I searched a lot about it but didn't get a proper answer I want to build my own bitcoin wallet and host it on my website for my personal usage and other visitors use.

If someone know that how to do that then please send me some links for reference

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, you'll need to have full access to your server, because you need to be running a Bitcoin-node (constantly) connected to the Bitcoin Network. So a simple shared server won't cut it. You could connect to your remote Bitcoin-node. But in that case, you still need a server to run that node.

**The programmer's way:**

1. Install and run a Bitcoin-node on your server. [HOW](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin)
2. Learn how to use [JsonRPC](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29) in your preferred programming language.
3. Use the API to program your own virtual wallet.

(basically how all online wallets more or less function)

**The lazy programmer's way**

1. Install and run a Bitcoin-node on your server.
2. Use a third-party DIY self-hosted wallet, like [Coinpunk](https://github.com/kyledrake/coinpunk)

(Note: as indicated on the website, such projects are still very beta. Careful.)

Comment: How to install bitcoin node in system and how to call api's from it ?

Answer (score 2):

Even better is if you use a multisig wallet with an offline node signing for transactions through a controlled and logged limited interface, or OTP
Full automation is always a risk.  You are then trusting your automation to be uncompromised